# Swift reduce/flatten Dictionary<String,Dictionary> to Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

> Convert this

```
[ 
   "Cat" : ["A" : 1, "B": 2], 
   "Mat" : ["C" : 3, "D": 4]
]
```

> Into

```
[
    "A" : 1, 
    "B" : 2,
    "C" : 3,
    "D" : 4
]
```

Without using a loop. In other terms using functions like reduce, flatmap.

The `source` can be of **type** `Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>`

---

So far I've managed to reduce the Dictionary to an array of Dictionary

```
let flatten = source.flatMap({ (k,v) -> [String: String]? in
                            return v
                        })

// flatten = [["A" : 1, "B": 2], ["C" : 3, "D": 4]]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, since the "flattening" is likely a synchronous operation, you might want to replace your completion handler (which kind of implies an async operation) to a function returning a tuple or, even better, an enum with two cases for "result" and "errors".

Comment: @dr_barto completion handler is not an issue. My concern is converting this 2D Dictionary to an Array of Dictionary. I was trying to use `reduce` this dictionary and I know the solution is either to use reduce, flatMap or merging the dictionary but I am just confused where to begin.

Comment: @vadian Nothing that I can do in that. Have to go with the flow. I can handle this using two for loops but I was hoping to make the code much shorter.

Comment: Again, I think you should post some code. Without that, it's hard to figure out where the problem lies. If `reduce` gives you a hard time, why not try a simple nested `for` loop to access all strings and put them in a `var` result?

Comment: @dr_barto I am handling this using for loops but I was hoping to make the code much shorter.

Comment: Ok, understood. Unfortunately, 90% of your question's text are not related to your actual intent. No need to explain the JSON, the decoding, the data model etc. What really matters is a) the input data (dict of dicts, check), b) the desired output (array of dicts, check), and c) your current implementation (still missing). Sorry for being so picky, but SO is not about doing the coding work for you, it's rather about helping you find solutions for your issues.

Comment: @dr_barto I posted the rest of the code as the question is rather short.

Comment: There's nothing better than short questions... ok, good luck to you, I'm out since you consistently refuse to post _your actual code_.

Comment: @dr_barto Updated the question with cleaner text

Comment: I’m not at a computer right now, but doesn’t Dictionary have something like `values` which returns an array of all values? You could then just flatten that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option:

```
let dictionary = [
    "Cat" : ["A" : 1, "B": 2],
    "Mat" : ["C" : 3, "D": 4]
]

let merged = dictionary
   // take values, we don't care about keys
   .values
   // merge all dictionaries
   .reduce(into: [:]) { (result, next) in
      result.merge(next) { (_, rhs) in rhs }
   }
print(merged) // ["B": 2, "A": 1, "C": 3, "D": 4]
```